# How do you signal a process (PID) to restart in the same shell where it is running, from another shell using bash?

Tags: bash

I have one terminal open with a java server running. I can easily get the process-ID (PID) of this JAR process. From another terminal, I want to signal this process to stop and restart in that same terminal where is is currently running. Is this possible using bash? Is there any signal i can send to the PID to make it stop and start again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From another terminal, I want to signal this process to stop and restart in that same terminal where is is currently running. Is this possible using bash?

You can send signals to a process via the `kill` command.  You may need to either be a privileged user or have the same UID as the process you're signaling.

But read on ...

> Is there any signal i can send to the PID to make it stop and start again?

If you mean "stop" as in terminate and "[re]start" as in run from the beginning as if a new process, then there is no signal for which that is the default handling.  A process could provide such behavior in response to a signal of its choice, but you cannot evoke it from an arbitrary process.

On the other hand, if you want to "stop" in the sense of temporarily suspending operations, and to "start" in the sense of resuming from such a stop, then there are `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT`, for which the default handling should suffice.  Be aware, however, that stopping a process in this sense probably will not take it out of the foreground (if it is in the foreground), and that processes can block, ignore, or provide their own handling for those signals.

Answer (score 1):

You can send signals with `kill`.

```
kill -s <SIGNAL> <PID>
```

will send the signal `<SIGNAL>` to the process with pid `<PID>`.

To stop and continue, you can use `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT`, which acts basically like hitting Ctrl-Z to pause a program on the terminal.